# A handshake problem with two parties

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

This problem was on a math contest some months ago:

Two countries agreed to resolve a border issue by talk and have sent (each of them) a delegation of $n>2$  diplomats. For each diplomat, strict protocoll regulates the number of delegacy members from the other contry's contingent that he or she needs to shake hands with. This number is 1 for the shortest diplomats of each contingent, 2 for the next ones in tallness and so on; the only exception being both delagations' tallest diplomats, who need to shake hands with $n-1$, rather than with $n$ members of the other delegation. Give an explicit formula for the number
of ways the regulations of the protocoll can be met!

I could not get a grip on this problem. But I have calculated it for some small $n$, and my guess is, that the answer is $F_{2n-1}$, where $F_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number. I have looked for formulas on OEIS, but I could not use them on this problem.

I would be grateful if you could give me some **hints** on how to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you tried to prove your conjecture by induction on $n$? Induction usually suits the Fibbanaci numbers; most of their properties are of a recursive nature.

Comment: Have you solved the problem for small $n$ directly? That's where I'd start (and hope to see some structure to use in organizing an induction).

Comment: Possible hint(?): The odd Fibonacci numbers satisfy the recurrence $F_{2n-1}=3F_{2n-3}-F_{2n-5}$, perhaps you can show this problem has the same recurrence? So, an arrangement with $n$ diplomats can be specified by choosing an arrangement with $n-1$ diplomats, then making a $3$-way choice, except that this overcounts by the number of arrangements with $n-2$ diplomats.

Comment: @PolymorphismPrince Yes, I have tried it. But I had no idea on how to use the induction hypothesis in this case. I can't get any recurrence relation working for this problem.

Comment: I couldn't see any structure yet. I have calculated it for some small n by counting all possible ways by hand and for some a bit larger n with a Python script.

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RamseyNumber.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not run through all the details, but I think you can split in 2 cases.

If the top two delegates of your party do not shake with the same set of people, then you can remove your top delegate and one handshake of your second highest delegate, as well as the opposite side's bottom delegate, and thereby reduce it to the $n-1$ case.

If the top two delegates of your party do shake hands with the same set of people, remove them both, as well as two of the bottom three delegates from the other party to reduce it to the $n-2$ case.

[**Edit:** Note the following is incorrect - see comments]
In the first case there are $n$ arrangements that reduce to the same smaller case, depending on which person the (removed) top delegate did not shake hands with. Similarly, in the second case I think there are always $1$ or $2$ arrangements that reduce to the same smaller case, but I'd have to spend more time to work out how often each occurs. The recurrence relation you then get is $T_n= n T_{n-1} + c T_{n-2}$, where $c$ is some fraction between $1$ and $2$.

Comment: For example if the top two delegates shake hands with everyone except the shortest delegates. Then I can't remove the shortest delegates, and the situation would be different from the n-2 case. But I might misunderstand what you are saying.

Comment: @Joseph If the top two delegates shake hands with the same people, then the one they don't shake with must be the other side's shortest delegate. Remove the top two and their handshakes. The other side now has one who does not shake hands (who you remove) and two that shake hands once. At least one of the latter must shake hands with the new tallest delegate, so remove that delegate and his handshake, and your new top two delegates will both do $n-3$ handshakes, as required.

Comment: I think this is not true. The one they don't shake hands with doesn't have to be the other side's shortest delegate. For example: Let n=4 and 4 be the tallest delegate, 1 the shortest. Let (x,y) be a handshake between x from the left party and y from the right party. Then (4,4), (4,3), (4,1), (3,4), (1,4), (3,3), (3,2), (2,3), (2,2) is a correct example, when the top two delegates does shake hands with the other side's shortest delegate, but doesn't shake hands with the second shortest delegate.

Comment: @Joseph We're talking about the case where the top two delegates shake hands with exactly the same set of people. In your example $3$ shakes hands with $\{2,3,4\}$ and $4$ with $\{1,3,4\}$, not the same set. If the two top delegates shake hands with the same set, it cannot include delegate $1$ from the other party because that delegate only shakes hands once..

Comment: @Joseph I made a small edit to clear up where I think the misunderstanding occured.

Comment: I think the recurrence relation you get is false. But your idea really solves the problem.

If the top two delegates of our party does not shake hands with the same set of people, then one of them has to shake hands with the shortest delegate from the opposite party. Then we can remove the one, who does not shake hands with the shortest delegate, and the shortest delegate, and one handshake from the other one in our party. This leads to the $n-1$ case. So we get $2T_{n-1}$, because there are two cases: If the tallest doesn't shake hands with the shortest or if the second tallest.

Comment: In the other case: We can remove the two tallest delegate from our party. And the second shortest delegate from the opposite party. This leads to the case where our party has to shake hands $n-2, n-3, ..., 1$ times (we have $n-2$ delegate). And the other party $n-3,n-3,n-4,...,2,1,1$ times (they have $n-1$ delegate). Now our tallest delegate has to shake hands with at least one of the other parties shortest delegate. This leads to the $n-2$ case, so we get $2T_{n-2}$, but we are counting two times the case, where the tallest delegate shake hands with both of the shortest delegates.

Comment: Which leads to the $n-3$ case, so we get: $T_n=2T_{n-1}+2T_{n-2}-T_{n-3}$ which is according to the OEIS is a known formula for the series I mentioned. Sorry for the long comments. 

Thank you! Your idea was the key here.

Answer (score 2):

#### Hint

Let us label the people $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ in one delegation, and $b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n$ in the other. Here, $a_i$ must shake hands with $i$ people for $1\le i\le n-1$, while $a_n$ must shake hands with $n-1$ people, and similarly for $b_i$.

Let $T_n$ be the number of ways for everyone to shake hands. You can get a recurrence for $T_n$ by considering who delegate $a_1$ shake hands with. For each possible person $b_i$ that $a_1$ shakes with, there will be a number of forced handshakes. If you then eliminate all people whose handshakes requirements are filled, then you get a smaller version of the same problem remaining, which gives a  recurrence. You can then show that $F_{2n-1}$ obeys the same recurrence.

Figuring out the forced handshakes is the fun and tricky part. If above is all the hint you need, then good. Otherwise, I have illustrated the forced handshakes for four of the cases below hidden behind spoiler blocks.

1. If $a_1$ shakes hands with $b_n\dots$

   > then $b_{n-1}$ cannot shake hands with $a_1$, so $b_{n-1}$ must shake with everyone else. Now, if you remove people $a_1$ and $b_{n-1}$ and their handshakes, while decreasing the required handshakes for the remaining delegates appropriately, then satisfying the remaining delegates ($a_2,a_3,\dots,a_{n}$ and $b_1,\dots,b_{n-2},b_n$) is exactly the smaller problem with $n-1$ delegates on each side.
2. If $a_1$ shakes hands with $b_{n-1}\dots$

   > Same as idea as previous case. We recurse to $T_{n-1}$.
3. If $a_1$ shakes hands with $b_{n-2}\dots$

   > Now, both $b_n$ and $b_{n-1}$ shake hands with everyone besides $a_1$. This means $a_1,b_{n-1}$ and $b_n$ are satisfied. Furthermore, $a_2$ is satisfied, since they shook hands with $b_{n-1}$ and $b_n$. Removing $a_1,a_2,b_{n-1}$ and $b_n$ leaves the smaller problem with $n-2$ delegates, counted by $T_{n-2}$.
4. If $a_1$ shakes hands with $b_{n-3}\dots$

   > As before, both $b_n$ and $b_{n-1}$ shake hands with everyone besides $a_1$. This means that $a_2$ is satisfied (again). This means that $b_{n-2}$ must shake hands with everyone except $a_1$ and $a_2$, since $b_{n-2}$ needs $n-2$ handshakes. Furthermore, $a_3$ is now satisfied. Removing $a_1,a_2,a_3,b_{n-2},b_{n-1},b_n$ leaves a smaller problem with $n-3$ delegates, counted by $T_{n-3}$.

You can figure out how the pattern continues. The resulting recurrence, again behind a spoiler block since this is practically the answer:

> $T_n=2T_{n-1}+T_{n-2}+T_{n-3}+\dots+T_1$